# How to test if jailbreak measure work without jailbroken device

Tags: ios, jailbreak

We have an iOS app and one of the items flagged from a penetration test was that the app will still load on a jailbroken device

We currently do not have a jailbroken device and are struggling to find one

Are there other ways to unit test that the code works? Are there any emulators/simulators that allow you to mimic a jailbroken device?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

You need a real jailbroken device to do any reliable tests (iOS 12.2 is currently the last jailbrakable one - see [this](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Jailbreak) for current status). Each jailbrake differs, hence detection ideally should account for that. Even Apple itself has no reliable method to achieve this (there used to be an API for that way back around iOS4 times, but it was withdrawn).

You could mock the system API for file detection of Cydia.app and such in a unit test, but that would not really test anything.